# Error on Magento one page check out

Tags: error, payment-methods, onestepcheckout

All payment methods either cause a "there was an error processing your order" or "user authentication failed". But the order will often go through on both Magento and PayPal...but not the credit card on PayPal advanced. I've checked the logs but can't figure out what the issue is. Even saved cc and purchase order throw and error.

Comment: So, what did you change since it worked the last time?

Comment: You should also check the output of the AJAX requests with your browsers developer toolbar.

Comment: Clearing the session folder in var/ ended up fixing it. I'll try and find the post that gave me the suggestion and credit them.